# Determine the closure, interior and boundary of the set $ S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb {R^2}:0<x^2+y^2<1\}.$

Tags: general-topology

Although I know that this is an annular region and I understand the definition of closure, interior and boundary, I am finding it hard to come with up with a proof of these.

On an intuitive level, these are my answers:

i) closure $ S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb {R^2}:0\leq x^2+y^2\leq1\}.$

ii) interior $S =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb {R^2}:0<x^2+y^2<1\}.$

iii) Boundary $ S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb {R^2}:x^2+y^2=1\} \cup \{\mathbf0\}. $

Let me know if I'm right or wrong and please provide detailed topological proofs for each of the three parts.

Comment: I believe it is more proper to call this a punctured disk.

Comment: For ii), choose a point in $S$.  Show that there exists a ball around it contained in $S$.  Thus every point in $S$ is in the interior.  Now show that any other point is not contained in the interior.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about each of the parts. But I leave it to you to provide proofs as this is good experience. A hint for each:

I) Do II and III first, then how do you get I?

II) Find a neighborhood, i.e. disc, about $(x,y)$ still contained in the circle that does not contain also the origin. Maybe consider the disc of radius $\epsilon$ at $(x,y)$, and think what is the distance to the 'closest' bad point, i.e. a point on the circle or the origin. Can you then even explicitly produce a radius so that the neighborhood is contained in the set.

III) Show that every neighborhood of each point (not the origin) in this set contains points both in and out of the set. The origin has this property and is not in the interior but is in the closure.

Note you can also show I, by showing a neighborhood of every point contains points in the set, then you show II, these together give you - by definition - III.

Comment: I + II also gives III.

Comment: @ε--δ I said that at the end.